# Multiply Two different columns from two different Dataframes with specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two different dataframes . They have the same columns but different rows. I need to multiply row from 2020 to 2023 of X DataFrame with percent Y DataFrame.

X DataFrame 2020: 300 multiply 0.2 and 40 multiply 0.4.

I will apply to like too many columns that is why I need to automate it. Would you please help me to figure out?

[image]

Comment: Show the dataframes as properly formatted text in the question, not as image or external link.

Comment: Y dataframe is one row only? All rows from X will be multiplied with 0.2 and 0.4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`X.loc[2020:2023] = X.loc[2020:2023] * Y.loc['percent']`